# Cosmos SQL where sessions[any].venues[any].id = this

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Using this structure as an example, saved in a Cosmos database (course-database) in a collection (course-collection):

```
{
    "courseId": "courseId",
    "sessions": [
        {
            "sessionId": "sessionId1",
            "venues": [
                {
                    "id": "venueId1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "venueId2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sessionId": "sessionId2",
            "venues": [
                {
                    "id": "venueId3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "venueId4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do you create the SQL:

**Count the total number of courses, where a course has at least one session, which has at least one venue, which has an ID equals to e.g. venueId3**

I've got this so far, but it restricts to the first item of the list, as opposed to just any:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.sessions[0].venues[0].id = "id"
```

Comment: JSON_SEARCH() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search should help.

Comment: FYI you tagged this question with multiple (and completely different) database engines. I removed your `mysql` tag, as it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was **join**:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id)
FROM c 
JOIN s in c.sessions
JOIN v in s.venues
WHERE CONTAINS(v.id,"venueId3")
```

You would then add a new **join** the deeper in the JSON you would want to go e.g. if venues had an array of contacts:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id)
FROM c 
JOIN s in c.sessions
JOIN v in s.venues
JOIN co in v.contacts
WHERE CONTAINS(co.id,"contactId")
```

Comment: This is not correct. Check the case when any course has multiple sessions on the same venue, and it does not work when venue ids names intersect each other (ex: `venueId31` vs `venueId3`)